# Why is my Keyless entity being built in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I have a few keyless entities and when I run the `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands, these entities are actually being built in the database, is this normal? From my understanding keyless entities are only used to map results and I should not be seeing them in my SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is an example of one of the entity I have defined in the `OnModelCreating` method :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DataRoomFile>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasNoKey();

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.DataRoomFolderId, e.DocumentId }, "IX_DataRoomFiles").IsUnique();

        entity.Property(e => e.DataRoomFolderId)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasColumnName("DataRoomFolderID");
        entity.Property(e => e.DocumentId).HasColumnName("DocumentID");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.DataRoomFolder).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DataRoomFolderId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_DataRoomFiles_DataRoomFolders");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Document).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DocumentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_DataRoomFiles_Documents");
    });
}
```

Comment: An entity that doesn't map to a table, can't have an index or any named constraints. Neither can it be added for the DB to generate a value. So, since you are defining all of those things, maybe EF Core is assuming you want a real table?

Comment: Probably you need [Exclude tables from migrations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#exclude-tables-from-migrations)